# How to create json using textviews? android studio

Tags: java, json, android-studio

i want to create a json like this:

```
{
"blogs":{  
   "blog":{
      "id":"","name":"","date":"","cant_post":0
       },
        "detailblog":[{
          "id":"","name":"","date":0,"cant_post":0,
          "creator":0,"theme":0
        },
        {
          "id":"","name":"","date":0,"cant_post":0,
          "creator":0,"theme":0
        },
        {
          "id":"","name":"","date":0,"cant_post":0,
          "creator":0,"theme":0
        }]
   }
}
```

from my textviews

```
name = txtName.getText().toString;
id = txtId.getText().toString;
```

etc

but i do not know how, neither know how the {} [] are added to json

can someone explain me or tell me an how to create it? thanks

Comment: Use `JSONObject`s and `JSONArray`s. [Here](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidJSON/article.html) is a tutorial.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! So, what have you tried?

Comment: @Andreas thank you! nothing yet, I'm a little bit confused

Comment: @Kartik I will check it, thanks!

Comment: Please update once you have tried something. I would suggest to do more Google search first, when you are stuck

Comment: @Andreas Ok, I'm reading everything I can, and I'm going to try my best, else I'm not gonna learn. you're totally right

Comment: please fix the json structure to get  a proper answer

Comment: @TouhidulIslam i think it its more clear now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's solve via a bottom up approach

1.create `detailblog` array

```
JSONObject detailblog1 = new JSONObject();

    try {
        detailblog1.put("id","");
        detailblog1.put("name","");
        detailblog1.put("date",0);
        detailblog1.put("cant_post",0);
        detailblog1.put("creator",0);
        detailblog1.put("theme",0);

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    JSONObject detailblog2 = new JSONObject();

    try {
        detailblog2.put("id","");
        detailblog2.put("name","");
        detailblog2.put("date",0);
        detailblog2.put("cant_post",0);
        detailblog2.put("creator",0);
        detailblog2.put("theme",0);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    JSONObject detailblog3 = new JSONObject();

    try {
        detailblog3.put("id","");
        detailblog3.put("name","");
        detailblog3.put("date",0);
        detailblog3.put("cant_post",0);
        detailblog3.put("creator",0);
        detailblog3.put("theme",0);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();

    jsonArray.put(detailblog1);
    jsonArray.put(detailblog2);
    jsonArray.put(detailblog3);
```

2.complete the `blog` JSONObject

```
JSONObject blogs= new JSONObject();

    try {

        blogs.put("blog",blog);
        blogs.put("detailblog",jsonArray);

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

3.complete the `blogs` JSONObject

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
    try {
        json.put("blogs",blogs);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Log.d("json",json.toString());
```

Comment: Thanks! Just a question, in json object .  blogs .  it is: blogs.put("blog", blogs); blogs.put("detailblog", jsonArray); right?

Comment: @hernyval nice catch, i missed it :)